# Laravel Pagination in eloquent ORM with()

Tags: pagination, laravel-4

I have used pagination in laravel and that time the query is very simple. So I have manage to work on it with no problem. But this time, I have a complicated query.

Below is the query:

```
$data['list'] = User::select('id')
                ->with(array('contacts.contact_fields' => function($query)
                {
                    $query->join('default_contact_method', 'contact_fields.field_type', '=', 'default_contact_method.id')
                          ->where('contact_fields.is_deleted', '=', 0);
                }))
                ->with(array('contacts' => function($query)
                {
                    $query->select('contact_types.type AS type_name')
                          ->join('contact_types', 'contacts.type', '=', 'contact_types.id')
                          ->where('contacts.is_deleted', '=', 0)
                          ->paginate(2);
                }))
                ->where('id', '=', $user_id)
                ->get();
```

I have used `paginate()` inside the `with()` because I want to paginate the contacts and it is working fine. My Problem is on the view end. I can't show the links.

On view:

```
{{ $list->links() }} // not working
{{ $list[0]->contacts->links() }} // also not working
```

On `{{ $list[0]->contacts->links() }}`

Error message `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links()`

can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Paginate the contacts of the user?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: `paginate()` the outer, manually set `->contacts = Paginator::make()` for the inner after eager loading with `get()`.

First, `$list->links()` wouldn't work because `->get()` returns a Collection, not a Paginator instance. So either use `->paginate()` on the overall query or construct a Paginator instance manually (check the docs).

As for `contacts->link` not working it could be one of two things. Your first `with()` has a nested relation (`contacts.contact_fields`) so it may be loading the contacts for you with the built-in eager loading. If that's not the case, then the other probably culprit is what `get()` actually does behind the scenes:

```
public function get($columns = array('*'))
{
    $models = $this->getModels($columns);

    // If we actually found models we will also eager load any relationships that
    // have been specified as needing to be eager loaded, which will solve the
    // n+1 query issue for the developers to avoid running a lot of queries.
    if (count($models) > 0)
    {
        $models = $this->eagerLoadRelations($models);
    }

    return $this->model->newCollection($models);
}
```

Note the `newCollection` - so even if you actually have a Paginator instance, it actually makes a Collection instance behind the scenes out of the items.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I have used manual pagination. My problem now is why it is still showing all the contacts? I can show the links of the pagination.